# PHP parse file after include

Tags: php

here's what I'm wanting to do:

```
<? include 'header.php' ?>
some html
<? include 'footer.php' ?>
```

in header.php...

```
<? //bunch of code
if (something){
//some stuff here, but no close brace
?>
```

in footer.php....

```
<? } //close the if brace ?>
```

Is this possible? I keep getting parse errors.

Thanks.

Comment: Most of the time I use `header.php` & `footer.php` is to generate the literal `header` & `footer` for a web-page. The php logic is confined to the files itself. You cannot extend it in between files. Although maybe you already know, include files **EVEN** need their `<?php` &  `?>` tags even if include call already enclosed in these tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Your brackets all need to be in the same file.

If you want to conditionally include HTML, put your logic in the file that `include`s *header.php* and *footer.php*

```
<?php include 'header.php' ?>
<?php if (/* something */): ?>
some html
<?php else : ?>
some other html
<?php endif; ?>
<?php include 'footer.php' ?>
```

Also, don't use ASP-style (`<? ?>`) short-open tags. They're being deprecated. You can still use `<?= ?>` to output variables and such.

[Here's an interesting conversation on that topic.](http://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg41839.html)

[And here's the notes from the PHP manual.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)

Comment: Since when are short tags being deprecated? I agree that they shouldn't be used, but they're certainly not being removed from the engine. Do you have a source to back that up?